Multithreading does not work in Release configuration
I have a program that computes some complicated math stuff inside a loop. I simplified it to the following:
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

struct Test
{
    int threads = 4;
    int threads_complete = 0;

    bool idle = true;
    bool stop = false;

    std::mutex mtx;

    // A single task
    void task(int n)
    {
        bool done = false;

        while (!stop)
        {
            if (idle || done) continue;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3 * (n + 1); i++)
            {
                printf("Task %d, iteration %d of %d\n", n, i, 3 * (n + 1));

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
            }

            done = true;

            // Lock thread to increment the counter
            mtx.lock();
            threads_complete++;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }

    // Launch multiple tasks
    void do_tasks()
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> v;

        // Start multiple threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            v.emplace_back(&Test::task, this, i);
        }

        // Launch subtasks in threads
        idle = false;

        // Wait for all tasks to finish
        while (threads_complete != threads);

        // Stop all the cycles inside tasks
        stop = true;

        // Await for threads to quit
        for (auto& t : v)
        {
            t.join();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;

    test.do_tasks();

    printf("\nDone\n");

    getchar();
}


The programs works as expected in Debug printing all the Task ... lines and Done in the end. However, when I run it in Release, the threads are seemed to be ignored completely and only Done is printed in the console.

You have data races since you modify non-atomic variables from one thread while other threads may be reading it.

idle and stop need synchronization, threads_complete is missing synchronization on the read side.

Whenever a debug build runs and a release build does not, you have bugs. So what Ted says, or learn to use std::mutex and std::scoped_lock

Unrelated: There will be quite a lot of spinning, burning CPU cycles, from what I can see. When a task is finished, it now enters a busy loop, just waiting for stop to get set and then it returns from the function. It'd be cheaper to just return when it's finished directly instead.

When a debug build works and a release build fails, it's a safe bet your code has Undefined Behavior.

You should create a constant temporary variable to contain "3 * (n + 1)", and use the variable in the for expression.  This will prevent the expression evaluated for each iteration.  (Note: smart compilers at high optimizations may perform this technique)  It also provides the capability of placing a breakpoint before the for statement to see the value of the expression, when debugging.

Some recommendations: 1) Dial your compilers warnings up to 11 (and actually fix the warnings). 2) Use sanitizers (like address sanitizer (asan), undefined behaviour sanitizer (ubsan) and thread sanitizer (tsan). 3) Do 1&2 with multiple different compilers (like gcc, clang & msvc), they all spot different issues (and test both debug and release builds). 4) Read about ub (read not just that page, but also all the linked articles at the end). 5) Read up on thread safety and synchronization primitives, atomics and memory barriers etc.


Use static analysis tools like, for example, clang-tidy to find even more issues.


I added std::atomic to all variables that are used in task() and it solved the problem.

The snippet works for me. Use std::condition_variable.
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdio>
#include <chrono>

struct Test
{
    int threads = 4;
    int threads_complete = 0;

    bool idle = true;
    bool stop = false;

    std::mutex mtx;
    std::condition_variable condition;

    // A single task
    void task(int n)
    {
        bool done = false;

        while (true)
        {
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                if (stop) break;
                if (idle || done) continue;
            }


            for (int i = 0; i <= 3 * (n + 1); i++)
            {
                printf("Task %d, iteration %d of %d\n", n, i, 3 * (n + 1));
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
            }

            done = true;

            // Lock thread to increment the counter
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                threads_complete++;
                if (threads_complete == threads)
                {
                    condition.notify_one();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Launch multiple tasks
    void do_tasks()
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> v;

        // Start multiple threads
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        {
            v.emplace_back(&Test::task, this, i);
        }

        // Launch subtasks in threads
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            idle = false;
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to finish
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            condition.wait(lock, [this] { return threads_complete == threads; });
        }

        // Stop all the cycles inside tasks
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            stop = true;
        }

        
        condition.notify_all();

        // Await for threads to quit
        for (auto& t : v)
        {
            t.join();
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test test;

    test.do_tasks();

    printf("\nDone\n");

    getchar();
}

